# Access - 3rd Left join with multiple criteria not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am trying to consolidate data from multiple tables (at least 6) using LEFT JOINs. I am getting an error ‘JOIN EXPRESSION NOT SUPPORTED’ when I go beyond adding a 3rd LEFT JOIN to the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
(Flat_File ff
left join Cost_Drivers cd on cd.Cost_Driver_Reported_Name = ff.Cost_Driver)
left join BM_IAA bmiaa on bmiaa.Section_Name = cd.Cost_Driver_Billing_Model_Section_Name)
left join BM_Allocations bma 
on
(bma.Fiscal_Year = ff.Fiscal_Year) and (bma.Section_Name = cd.Cost_Driver_Billing_Model_Section_Name)
```

Doing this gives me the "Join expression not supported" error. However If I remove one of the criteria in the final Left Join, it works. Is there a syntax issue I'm having?

Comment: I guess if you remove all `(` and `)`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, if you have more than one jointure, you **MUST** surround all your joins with parenthesis.

Your query should be

```
SELECT *
FROM
(((Flat_File ff
left join Cost_Drivers cd on cd.Cost_Driver_Reported_Name = ff.Cost_Driver)
left join BM_IAA bmiaa on bmiaa.Section_Name = cd.Cost_Driver_Billing_Model_Section_Name)
left join BM_Allocations bma 
   on ((bma.Fiscal_Year = ff.Fiscal_Year) and (bma.Section_Name = cd.Cost_Driver_Billing_Model_Section_Name)))
```

Comment: should --> must.

Comment: sacré @Andre :)

Comment: Thanks for much for your answer, however I am still getting the error. I think it has to do with the extra criteria in the final join. If I remove either one of them, the error doesn't occur.